# Access value from XAML and code behind file

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, static, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to access a value, which should be shared between the XAML and the code behind file. Therefore I thought I could use [`x:static` markup extension](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml_markup_extensions/#The_xStatic_Markup_Extension). This is my code:

DetailPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppName.Pages.DetailPage;assembly=AppName"
             x:Class="AppName.Pages.DetailPage">

  <Grid x:Name="masterGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:Static local:DetailPage.Width}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Grid>
</ContenPage>
```

DetailPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace AppName.Pages
{
    public partial class DetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static readonly double Width = 40;
        // ...
    }
}
```

If I start the app I get

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

If I remove `x:static` markup extension, the pages works fine. I tried with different namespaces, but I didn't had a success.

**Solution:**

With the help of [Karel Tamayo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39516817/426227) I got it working:

DetailPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppName.Pages;assembly=AppName"
             x:Class="AppName.Pages.DetailPage">

  <Grid x:Name="masterGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:Static local:DetailPage.Width}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Grid>
</ContenPage>
```

DetailPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace AppName.Pages
{
    public partial class DetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static readonly GridLength Width = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Absolute);
        // ...
    }
}
```

As one can perhaps see from the namespace, the `DetailPage` is in the folder `Pages`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Width property is expecting one object of type `GridLength` while your are assigning a `double` value.

Try this in your DetailPage.xaml.cs:

```
public static readonly GridLength Width = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Pixel);
```

And test your app again.
You can configure the unit to `GridUnitType.Pixel`, `GridUnitType.Star` or `GridUnitType.Auto` according to your needs.

Comment: You are correct. [`ColumnDefinition`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ColumnDefinition/) takes [`GridLength`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.GridLength/) as `Width`. `Absolute`, `Auto`, `Star` are available for `GridUnitType`. Now I tried `public static readonly GridLength Width = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Absolute);`, but I still get `TargetInvocationException`. There seems still to be something missing ...

Comment: OK, now I got it. I'll edit my question to post the final solution. Thanks for your help :-)